# If $X$ is a non-compact metric space, can $X^n$ ever be compact?

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Do there exist metric spaces $X$ such that $X^n$ is compact even though $X$ is not? Since compact spaces can have non-compact subspaces, e.g. $[0,1)\subset[0,1].$

Comment: If $A \times B$ is compact (for the product topology), then both $A$ and $B$ are compact.

Comment: I don't even know why I wrote that.

Comment: Yes, if $n=0$...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, since the image of a compact map by a continuous map is compact and the projection $p:X^n\rightarrow X$ is continuous and surjective.